# Java : spliting a string into integers

Tags: java, string, date, split, integer

I have this string `10-12-1999` and I want to store the values into a different variables like this:

So I have this string `data= 10-12-1999` and I want to store it like this

```
int day =10;
int month = 12;
int year = 1999;
```

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Well you could use `split("-")`, but IMO you should store it as a Date using a `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Why do you think a day is 10, and month is 12?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert string to int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the **`public String[] split(String regex)`** method available in the String class :

I hope this helps :-

```
String date="10-12-1999";
String [] s1=date.split("-");
int day=Integer.parseInt(s1[0]);
int month=Integer.parseInt(s1[1]);
int year=Integer.parseInt(s1[2]);
System.out.println("Day->"+day+"    Month->"+month+"    Year->"+year);
```

This will help extracting out all the date elements and you can assign them to all the requisite variables!

Answer (score 6):

```
String data = "10-12-1999"
String[] dataArray = data.split("-");
int day = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[0])
int month = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[1])
int year = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[2])
```